# "when" and "would" in a sentence

Tags: grammar, past-tense

I would like to use *when* and *would* in the following sentence:

> When I would study on the morning of an exam I would say something like that.

So, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "would" instead if "used to" if the verb, as in this case, is active to form the imperfect tense.

Comment: thanks but can i say that my sentence is correct ?

Comment: yes, it is correct, as would also be "used to" and "studied"

Comment: coud you please rewrite my sentence with "used to" and "studied"

Comment: When I used study on the morning of an exam I used to say something like that

Comment: When I studied on the morning of an exam I said something like that